# return x = argument etc.. on the same line in python? Newbie question

Tags: python, return

I've started learning python very recently so this is probably just babysteps i'm taking but i can't really figure out why these 2 examples below doesn't work when it seems to me to be the same, and in fact i've seen some examples of a similar way of doing it.

```
def multiply_by_two(value):
    x = value * 2
    return x
    #return x = value * 2  <-- This doesn't work.. Gives me a syntax error, why?

def divide_by_two(value):
    x = value / 2
    return x   
    #return x = value / 2  <-- This doesn't work.. Gives me a syntax error, why?

y = multiply_by_two(2)
z = divide_by_two(2)

print("2 * 2 = " + str(y) + "\n2 / 2 = " + str(z))
```

Comment: `return` expects an expression, which `=` isn't. What's your intent with `return x = value * 2` though? `x` goes out of scope as soon as the function ends, so there's no point in reassigning it there.

Comment: So, you can just use `return value * 2`

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'm just learning the basics atm so not trying to make anything useful really, i found something similar like my example on a tutorial where it stated that you could write it like that but now when i think about it, it makes no sense at all to assign it to a variable. Thanks again for all the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment with `=` forms a statement in Python, not an expression. As a result, it doesn't evaluate into a value that could be used by something like `return`.

There is an operator for doing an assignment, that's treated like an expression (rather than a statement) and colloquially called [the walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), `:=`. You *could* right this:

```
def multiply_by_two(value):
    return x := value * 2
```

...but it would make no sense.

`x` is useless. Remove it. Just write:

```
def multiply_by_two(value):
    return value * 2
```